# Combine two List in C# using For Each

Tags: c#, list

I have two list objects in c# as mentioned below

```
List A

[0]
    Count="0",
    CountType="0",
    InvTpeCode="DLX"
[1]
    Count="0",
    CountType="0"
    InvTpeCode="STD"

List B

[0]
    Count="2",
    CountType="17"
[1]
    Count="12",
    CountType="14"
```

I have tried using foreach to update list a value with list b values but unfortunately i am not able to bring the desired output.

Note : Both the list are of same size only

Comment: Can you please mention the expected output?

Comment: So what should be the value of A[0] ?

Comment: Are two collections going to be of same size? If not, what is the comparison done between?

Comment: Could you add some code to your question where you can show what you've tried to do please? It's not clear if you are using objects or not. That might be part of the problem.

Comment: Simply for loop may useful in your case

Comment: @Berkay it should be updated from List B so List A[0] should be updated with List B[0]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `for`-loop you can also use `Zip`

```
var result = A.Zip(B, (a, b) => new Item {
                             InvTpeCode = a.InvTpeCode,
                             CountType = b.CountType, 
                             Count = b.Count });
```

Comment: +1 for not pasting the same answer as everyone else and because I've never come across `Zip()` before. Love it.

Comment: @fubo You saved my day.What i did was read an xml in the process i got all xml data separated because of using attribute tag then i was finding a way to combine the split xml data but you made it easy which i was struggling for the whole day searching all answers.Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

If the lists are the same size then a for loop will be enough:

```
for (int i=0; i< A.Count();i++)
{
    A[i].Count = B[i].Count;
    A[i].CountType = B.CountType;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a foreach-loop is unpractible here, i would do the following:

```
for(int i=0; i < A.Count(); i++) 
{
    A[i].Count = B[i].Count;
    A[i].CountType = B[i].CountType;
}
```

But keep in mind this will die hard if List A is longer than B.

Comment: don't need the `-1` on `< A.Length -1`. If the list is `1` in length the loop will never start. Also, `Length` is only on arrays, I think you mean `Count()`

Comment: ya you are right, edited the answer. That do not seems to help the op too much as there are several answers with the same content...

Comment: yes there seems to be a lot of very similar answers to this. Thanks to comments, though, yours is at the top (for now) :)

Answer (score 0):

First assure that the lists are the same size.

```
var index = 0;
foreach ( ObjA itemA in listA) {
  replaceValues(ObjA, listB[index]);
  index++;
}
```

The method replaceValues should then replace the properties of ObjA with the properties of the item from listB (with the same position).
But I think it makes no sense to use an foreach here. A simple for-loop can be used - as you need the index of the current element anyway.